# Git-flow hotfix makes master being ahead of develop by 1 merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

We're using git-flow to simplify the process of handling features and fixes. But there's one thing that annoys me.

When I start a hotfix, git-flow creates new branch from master. Then I commit my fixes and do git-flow hotfix finish. The command does two separate merges: hotfix into master and hotfix into develop. Since the merges are separate, master and develop diverge by one revision: master becomes ahead of develop by 1 and develop ahead of master by N + 1.

That's normal if develop is ahead, but the fact that master is ahead annoys me.

Is there any neat solution to avoid this? I can always merge master into develop, but this seems as not following git-flow philosophy. Or probably I'm worrying for nothing and it's ok to have such a situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. You don't have to worry.